# Common solution for Xamarin.UWP and Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac, xamarin.uwp

I have a quick question, it would be great if anyone can clear it out. I wanted to develop a cross-platform application for Window OS and Mac OS.

I search it out a lot and found that we can create Window app with UWP and Mac OS app with the help of Xamarin.Mac but in that case, we are having a different solution for both Windows and Mac platform. We need a common solution for both the platform.

I will really appreciate if anyone can clarify how we need to proceed with the Cross-Platform development of Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The idea with xamarin is to separate UI and non UI code. You can share the non UI code between the UWP and Xamarin.Mac

Another approach is to use Xamarin.Forms which abstracts the UI code to be cross platform. The Xamarin.Forms implementation for Xamarin.Mac is stil in preview though

Comment: Sorry I can't use Xamarin.Forms. Is there other solution

Comment: Your question is very broad. Why can't U use xamarin.forms? It is exactly meant for the purpose. There is no general awnser to such a general question.

Comment: Yes, you are right but our client is very much concern about UI. And it is not recommended to use Xamarin.Forms if UI is the concern.

Comment: Wel if good UI is the concern U should use the first option. Shared code with different native UI layers. You can put in all code into one visual studio solution

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I can't create Xamarin.Mac in my Windows VS and Xamarin.UWP in Mac machine using either Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio. So how can I share code? Any solution.

Comment: Create a shared project (.Net standard Library or a Shared Project) for shared code. On windows add a UWP project to the solution. On Mac add a Mac project to the solution.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_3_-_setting_up_a_xamarin_cross_platform_solution/